# Does global warming even exist?

Tags: climate-change

The controversy around the existence of global warming is very prominent, and hot debate. There are as many people claiming that global warming doesn't exist, as there are claiming that it exists.

---

Example arguments claims may be as the following:

**Against (global warming doesn't exist):**

> No Significant and Prolonged Temperature Changes Since 1997 – Scientists who argue against global warming say global warming isn’t real because since the 90s there hasn’t been a significant temperature change. The upswing in the temperature started from 1975, continued till 1997 and the temperature has been flat since then which clearly states that there isn’t any significant change in temperature in last 17 years.

*There are many others including:*

- Not Enough Historical Data Available
- Arctic Ice Increased by 50% Since 2012
- Climate Models used are Proven to be Unreliable
- Early Predictions About the Effects of Warming Have Been Proven Wrong

---

**For (global warming exists):**

> Shrinking Glaciers – The glaciers on several mountain ranges, particularly in Greenland and Antarctica, are decreasing in size due to reduction in gases that help to maintain temperatures, and changes in the region's climate. Studies conducted by NASA’s Gravity Recovery and Climate Experiment show Greenland lost 36 to 60 cubic miles of ice every year between 2000 and 2006.

*There are many others including:*

- Rise in Ocean Temperature
- Rise in Earth’s Average Temperature
- Rise in Sea Level
- Increase in pest species
- Increase in "freeing" of detritus
- Ocean Acidification

Comment: @Sklivvz isn't the other question about human activity, while this one is simply whether or not the Earth has warmed?

Comment: related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19291/have-global-surface-temperatures-not-shown-significant-warming-since-the-late-19?lq=1

Comment: Either way, it's a dupe.

Comment: @Sklivvz my question is not how different factors deliberately carried out by humans can affect global warming, but more about the actual existence in general. There is a lot of evidence/theories for and against it.

Comment: If you look at the "Related" side bar there are at least a few questions which answer this one at least partially if not entirely. I merely pointed this to the highest voted.

Comment: @Sklivvz I agree, but recent data makes the case for warming even stronger http://nsstc.uah.edu/climate/

Comment: @DavePhD Find the most relevant existing question and add another answer, then. We don't need to revisit the issue just to add recent data.

Comment: @called2voyage yes, I agree

Comment: Many of the arguments given against have been answered individually here: No warming since 1997 here : http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19291/have-global-surface-temperatures-not-shown-significant-warming-since-the-late-19?rq=1 ; Arctic Ice Increased by 50% Since 2012 here: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/17695/did-the-arctic-ice-sheet-grow-by-60-from-2012-to-2013/17709#17709 ;

Comment: Climate Models used are Proven to be Unreliable here http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/17655/does-this-graph-show-climate-change-predictions-dont-meet-observations Early Predictions About the Effects of Warming Have Been Proven Wrong here http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/17136/can-some-simple-old-models-of-the-effect-of-co%E2%82%82-predict-temperature-better-than etc.

Comment: Beware of that date.  1998 was an exceptionally warm year, the deniers use it as a baseline to pretend there isn't warming rather than recognize it was an outlier.